# how to push in my branch and pull from master git

Tags: git, push, pull

Is it appropriate to do the following sequence :

```
git add [file names]
git commit [comments]
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout [my branch]
git merge master
git push
```

Comment: Correct in what sense?

Comment: if i follow this order of this steps i can have problems or not?the idea is i want to have the latest version from master without losing my updates in the code and then pushing the latest version with my updtes in my branch

Comment: I usually don't merge master into my branch, see git workflows (google) to see which workflow works best for you or your team

Comment: so it is correct to do add then commit then pull then push?

Comment: It could be correct for you, it depends on your workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to be able to push to different branch name?

You are almost there, but you miss some important step:

```
# Add the desired files to stage area
git add [file names]

# commit the changes
git commit [comments]

# switch to master branch
git checkout master

# git pull
# This is dangerous !!! if you are using git version <2.0
```

Read [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt) why (first paragraph).

---

#### How to do it in a simple way:

```
# Commit changes to your local branch 

# pull changes from the remote branch to your branch
# since you are already on your branch - you dont need to switch 
# to master branch. Simply grab the remote copy and merge it into
# your local branch using the pull command.
git pull origin master

# now your changes are merged with master
git push origin <branch_name>
```

Comment: Cool. glad to help. Rad this out to get some more usefull information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716